# Laravel 5: unstable display errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, amazon-ec2

I have a weird issue, Laravel 5 sometimes display `<HTML> </ HTML>` rather than display error msg, and next time when refresh display the error correctly,

[image]
[image]

using: Amazon EC2, Ubuntu 16.04, PHP7

Any suggestion? thanks,

Updates: storage permissions:
[image]

Updates: Laravel log

```
[2017-03-12 13:19:07] local.ERROR: Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException: A token is required in /var/www/html/api/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/JWTAuth.php:299
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/api/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/JWTAuth.php(188): Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth->requireToken(NULL)
#1 /var/www/html/api/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/JWTAuth.php(124): Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth->getPayload(NULL)
#2 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(221): Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth->authenticate(NULL)
#3 /var/www/html/api/app/Http/Middleware/info.php(21): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('authenticate', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): App\Http\Middleware\info->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Clos$
#5 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\H$
#6 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{cl$
#7 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illumi$
#8 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\H$
#9 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{clo$
#10 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illumi$
#11 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\$
#12 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Rout$
#13 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object$
#14 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\$
#15 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\$
#16 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(149): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#17 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illu$
#18 /var/www/html/api/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 {main}
```

Server Response details:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Connection: Close
Content-Type: text/html
Pragma: no-cache
refresh: 1; URL=http://54.200.51.42/api/public/login
```

Comment: What's the response code on those `<html></html>` pages ? Could it be that you hit the rate limit?

Comment: Status Code: 200 OK

Comment: The headers may also give an indication. Usually they have the PHP generated header included if PHP was ran. If they don't it's possible the problem lies outside the PHP part of the code and in the server configuration.

Comment: I edit post, with server response details,

Answer (score 0):

Check your `storage` folder:

- Already have permission for write: chown, chmod
- Have folder framework/sessions or not

And try to

`sudo chmod -R 777 storage`

`sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user storage`

`sudo chmod -R 777 storage/framework/sessions`

`sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user storage/framework/sessions`

Comment: Followed steps, issue still appear randomly

Comment: @mwafi Your `storage` already have enough sub folder: app, framework, logs, framework/cache, framework/sessions, ....?

Comment: And your WebService running with user:group is ec2-user:ec2-user right sir?

Comment: @mwafi Can you show one picture about current permission of these folder?

Comment: picture added to the Qs

Comment: @mwafi Please try `sudo chmod -R 755 root-laravel-direction` => `sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu root-laravel-direction` => `sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap` => `sudo chmod -R 777 storage`

Comment: Still same, I don't think it's a file permission issue

Comment: @mwafi Can you show `storage/logs/laravel.log` sir?

Comment: @mwafi This case too hard for guess problems. So can you try to review did you miss configure something in this tutorial or not sir: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Installation